# Get sqlite database from android app after sync from online database

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

I have a android app with prefiiled database, I can crack the prefiled data but after sync with online server, I still get old database.  I think new data is stored in memory and not written to database stored in assests. 
How can I get live sqlite database, app is currently using after sync .

Comment: Till now what you have tried? How to ask question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you mean pull out the database from the device which is currently in use?

Comment: yes, I can pull the old database which was placed during building the app, but if i want to get latest synced data, I can't get that @gopal_patil

Comment: update your sync process with code snippets in your question.

Comment: I have decompiled app, so their sync activity is using some ncryption to get data, only way to get data is after it is inserted into the sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Compare all objects that could change in old and new databases. Delete non-existent records, and insert new records.

Or alternatively just delete the old database, and download new database as replacement.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I have decompiled the app and hence I cannot change the code but just get sqlite from it's memory somehow

Answer (score 0):

By pull that file, you won't be able to get your new data.
You can try this, it will read your data and create new file from that.

```
public boolean backUpDB() {
        String currentDBPath = ""; //db path
                + "DB_NAME";
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
            File folder;
            folder = new File(
                    context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                            + "/backup_path/");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
            String path = folder + "";

            File SDPath = new File(path);
            if (!SDPath.exists()) {
                SDPath.mkdir();
            }
            try {
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
                byte dataa[] = new byte[input.available()];
                input.read(dataa);

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/"
                        + "DB_NAME");
                out.write(dataa);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Commons.printException("exception," + e + "");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```